# Cannot scale reputation by π

Tags: bug, unicoins

I'd like to scale my reputation by π, but I get an error complaining that it's not valid.

[image: failure]

Please add support for this - π is supported in other places on the site after all:
[image]

Comment: You can use an approximate value for π - 3.

Comment: @Oded I thought that was the exact value

Answer (score 6):

See the red banner.  (emphasis mine)

> The value must be a positive **integer** between 1 and 10

It doesn't however specify that the number be *real*, so I would fully expect complex numbers to be supported.  This should allow you to make your Imaginary Internet Points actually have an imaginary numeric value.

Comment: Right, that's why I said "Please add support". Oh, and yes π is a valid integer in base π. The banner doesn't specify the input base.

Comment: `Math.ceil(Math.pi)`?

Comment: @MikeyB If you're requesting a feature then you should tag the question as a feature request, not a bug.

Comment: @RUJordan Pi doesn't taste as good once it's bee on the ceiling.

Comment: @Servy I would assume the ceiling is cleaner than the floor :P

Comment: @RUJordan at least the floor gets washed regularly.  How often do you vacuum and mop the ceiling?

Comment: @Servy Anything in the world that doesn't work the way I want it to is a bug! :D

Comment: @psubsee2003 you don't wash your ceiling?!

Comment: _The value must be a positive integer between 1 and 10_: You didn't specify the base.

Comment: @devnull That means you don't know what base it will be interpreted as, but you still need to supply an integer for some base value.  π isn't an integer in any base, not even base π.  There is no addition field allowing you to supply your own base.

Comment: Actually, if it must be an integer between 1 and 10, then that rules out anything in ℂ: they do not lie “between” things in ℤ. I would explain, but alas the answer is too complex to fit within these margins.